# Partitioning vertex set of Outerplanar Graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

I am able to use induction method to partition the vertex set of any outerplanar graph into two sets say $X$ and $Y$ such that the two sets induce forests with maximum degree at most 2.

I was wondering if there could be any alternative method to do the proof?

Comment: Interesting. I think you can achieve this by setting nodes in $X$ (say) to be all those that are an even distance from an arbitrary start node (which is also in $X$ of course), and $Y$ all at odd distance from the same node.